# Access master page control from usercontrol of aspx which enclosed in master page

Tags: asp.net, dom-events, c#-2.0

I have a aspx page which enclosed in master page. My aspx page have user control (ASCX) from user control I am opening a pop up in which I want to get master page controls how can I do it.

Answer (score 6):

ASP.NET has internal property for each page 'Master'. From usercontrol you can travese the stack backwards to Usercontrols parent > Page > Master. If the control in master page is outside any contentplace holders, you can get the control using FindControl method. If it is inside any content place holders, you have to traverse to the content place holder and then you can find the control. The example is below.

**MASTER**

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
       <asp:Label ID="lblVal" runat="server" Text="MasterLabel"></asp:Label>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**CONTENT PAGE**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <test:uc ID="test" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

**USER CONTROL**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="WebUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebUserControl" %>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

**USERCONTROL CODE BEHIND**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MasterPage mstr = this.Parent.Page.Master as MasterPage;
        Label1.Text = (mstr.FindControl("lblVal") as Label).Text;
    }
```

In my case the Label in master page is outside content page.

Comment: Thts fine but i have to access in popup of user control i have tried some java script which would not able to get control of master page(in pop page(also an aspx page) of ascx control)